# Calling a Python function/class that takes an entire pandas dataframe or series as input, for all rows in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python class that takes a geopandas Series or Dataframe to initialize (specifically working with geopandas, but I imagine it to be the same solution as pandas). This class has attributes/methods that utilize the various columns in the series/dataframe. Outside of this, I have a dataframe with many rows. I would like to iterate through (ideally in an efficient/parallel manner as each row is independent of each other) this dataframe, and call a method in the class for each row (aka Series). And append the results as a column to the dataframe. But I am having trouble with this. With the standard list comprehension/pandas apply() methods, I can call like this e.g.:

```
gdf1['function_return_col'] = list(map((lambda f: my_function(f)), gdf2['date']))
```

But if said function (or in my case, class) needs the entire gdf, and I call like this:

```
gdf1['function_return_col'] = list(map((lambda f: my_function(f)), gdf2))
```

It does not work because 'my_function()' takes a dataframe or series, while what is being sent to it is the column names (strings) of gdf2.

How can I apply a function to all rows in a dataframe if said function takes an entire dataframe/series and not just select column(s)? In my specific case, since it's a method in a class, I would like to do this, or something similar to call this method on all rows in a dataframe:

```
gdf1['function_return_col'] = list(map((lambda f: my_class(f).my_method()), gdf2))
```

Or am I just thinking of this in the entirely wrong way?

Comment: If you're working row-wise, I think you need to look at `df.apply(func, axis=1)`. [pandarallel](https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/) can help you parallelize this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pandas dataframe method called "apply". 
Here is an example of using it for both row axis and column axis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [10, 20]})

df1 = df.apply(np.sum, axis=0)
print(df1)

df1 = df.apply(np.sum, axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Comment: thank you! i had tried apply earlier but it wasn't working, but after fixing some things it works. now if only i could get it to work with dask. thanks!